# Simplifying nested functor transformations

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, functor

Say I have 2 Functors `f0` and `f1` and I have some code that looks like —

```
f0.map(v0 => f1.map(v1 => f0f1(v0, v1)))
```

Is there a way simplify this such that I can use a for expression and make the code cleaner —

```
for { 
  v0 <- f0
  v1 <- f1
} yield f0f1(v0, v1)
```

The `map` function is available thru a syntactic sugar that looks like —

```
  implicit class FunctorOps[F[_], A](fa: F[A]) {
    def F = implicitly[Functor[F]]
    def map[B](ab: A => B): F[B] = F.map(fa)(ab)
  }
```

Comment: In my case its actually something like — `IO[Option[X]]`

Comment: I don't want to actually care about what the container of my value is, I want to apply transformations to what's inside

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez what are you all talking about? Where does `Future` come from, all of a sudden? Which implementation of `Functor` has a `map` which takes a single argument? They all take [two arguments](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Functor.scala), and the function usually comes second. Unclear what you're asking, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I am using Cats because of which `map` is added as a syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Tushar then it's unclear what the syntactic sugar is added to. What exactly are `f0` and `f1`. They aren't instances of `Functor[F]`, as it seems.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I have added the syntactic sugar that's automatically inserted by Cats

Comment: How are snippets from Cats supposed to clarify the types of `f0` and `f1` in your code? We know what the code in Cats looks like. We don't know what `f0` and `f1` in your code are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180990/discussion-between-tushar-and-andrey-tyukin).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `f0: F0[X]` and `f1: F1[Y]`, where both `F0` and `F1` have `Functor` instances, and `f: (X, Y) => Z`, the `for`-comprehension equivalent to

```
f0.map(x => f1.map(y => f(x, y)))
```

would be

```
for (x <- f0) yield for (y <- f1) yield f(x, y)
```

Example:

```
val f0 = Option(42)
val f1 = List(1, 2, 3)
for (x <- f0) yield for (y <- f1) yield x * y
```

produces:

```
res1: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(42, 84, 126))
```

whereas

```
for (y <- f1) yield for (x <- f0) yield x * y
```

produces

```
res2: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(42), Some(84), Some(126))
```

I'm not sure whether the `for` comprehension is much cleaner than the nested `map`s in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are after is possible in principle.

The nice `for` syntax you are after translates to something like

```
f0.flatMap(v0 => (f1.map(v1 => f0f1(v0, v1))))
```

The problem here is the `flatMap` part. For there to be a `flatMap` you need a
`Monad`, not only a `Functor`, or at least something with the `FlatMap`
instance. But `Monad`s, as opposed to `Functor`s, don't compose. So there is no
way to get a nested `Monad` automatically from `F[_]` and `G[_]`, even if both
of them are `Monad`s. [1]

You might get the nice syntax using some of the monad transformers, but they
don't (and can't) exist for all monads. [2]

For monads where there are transformers, something like what you want is possible:

```
val l: List[Int]      = List(1,2,3)
val o: Option[String] = Some("abc")

val ol: OptionT[List, String] = for {
  a <- OptionT.liftF(l)
  b <- OptionT.fromOption[List](o)
} yield a + b.toString
```

There are scala docs ([3]) if you are interested in `OptionT`.

Whether that's nicer or not lies in the eyes of the beholder.

That being sad, if you need this more often, you might want to write your own helper functions along the lines of

```
def combine2[F[_]: Functor, G[_]: Functor, A, B, C](
    fa: F[A],
    gb: G[B])(
    f: (A, B) => C
  ): F[G[C]] =
    fa.map(a => gb.map(b => (f(a, b))))
```

If you don't want to do this, one thing you can do is what @andrey-tyukin already mentioned. But I agree that it's probably best to just nest the calls to `map`.

Another thing you might want to look at is `Nested` [4]. It doesn't help you in this particular case, but it might help you reduce some of the nested `map`s down the road.

--

[1] http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/monads-do-not-compose/

[2] [Why is there no IO transformer in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056663/why-is-there-no-io-transformer-in-haskell)

[3] https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/data/OptionT.html

[4] https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/data/Nested.html