# Is this a generic transformer for any monad?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers

There have been claims that the `IO` monad has no monad transformer, or even cannot have a monad transformer. [Why is there no IO transformer in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056663/why-is-there-no-io-transformer-in-haskell)

First question: Then, what is this code? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/acme-iot-0.1.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-IO.html Is this not a monad transformer for `IO`, "adding `IO` capabilities to any monad" as the documentation says?

Second question: There is this blog post: http://h2.jaguarpaw.co.uk/posts/io-transformer/  where it is claimed that `IOT m a = (forall x. m x -> IO x) -> IO a` is a monad transformer for `IO` applied to an arbitrary foreign monad `m`. It is assumed, however, that the functions of type `m x -> IO x` must be monad morphisms. The blog post elaborates on this to show that (at least) the monad morphism laws hold for the map `m a -> IOT m a`.

Now, this construction seems to apply to arbitrary monads and seems to give a formula for a monad transformer for a completely arbitrary base monad `Base a`. The monad transformer `BaseT` is defined by:

```
 BaseT base m a = (forall x. m x -> base x) -> base a
```

Here the functions of type `forall x. m x -> base x` are assumed to be monad morphisms. (The code does not express that requirement in the type.)

Does this formula give a completely general monad transformer for any base monad `base` and any foreign monad `m`?

Are there monad morphisms `lift: m a -> BaseT base m a` and `hoist :: (forall x. m x -> n x) -> BaseT base m a -> BaseT base n a`?

Are there any other laws that a monad transformer must satisfy and `BaseT` does not satisfy?

One of my misgivings about `BaseT` is that the type `forall x. m x -> base x` could be void, for some `m` and `base`, even if we do not assume that it must be a monad morphism. There are some monads `m` and `base` for which there are simply no natural transformations of type `forall x. m x -> base x`, for example, `m a = Maybe a` and `base a = a`. So, in that case, the void type gets substituted into the formula and we get `BaseT base m a = Void -> m a`, which is equivalent to `Unit`. A monad transformer that is identically equal to `Unit` is useless for practical applications but does satisfy the monad morphism laws (as `Unit` is a lawful monad and any other monad can be mapped to `Unit` by a monad morphism). So, `BaseT base m` may not give a useful answer for some `base` and `m`. Does it mean that it is nevertheless useful when `base = IO`?

Comment: Implementing `lift` and `hoist` is easy, you should try it yourself. Also, you can find the laws which must be satisfied on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_transformer).

Comment: @Noughtmare The laws listed in wikipedia are not enough to ensure that a monad transformer is actually useful. For example, as I wrote in my post, we can just define `t m a = Unit` and it will satisfy all laws but it's completely useless. There must be more laws, at least there must be some non-degeneracy laws to ensure that a monad b's monad transformer applied to a monad `m` actually includes the effects of both monads.

Comment: @Noughtmare Implementing is easy, proving the monad morphism laws is less easy.

Comment: In light of your comments I'd recommend to focus your question more on one particular question. Is your question whether `BaseT` is useful (be careful to avoid asking for opinions), or whether it satisfies the laws (show where you get stuck in proving the laws), or whether it is possible to implement `lift` and `hoist`, or ...?

Comment: Already mentioned in the answers, but there exists the convention that Hackage packages which begin with "acme-" https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=acme are "joke" packages that do some thing in an extremely convoluted way, claim some kind of "safety" while in reality being really unsafe, or claim to do something that is actually impossible. The name of course is a reference to the fictional Acme corporation in the Road Runner cartoons https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acme_Corporation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`acme-iot`, as its name implies, is a joke package. It breaks purity. The following program prints when a value is *forced* (which would require `unsafeInterleaveIO` or `unsafePerformIO`).

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.Trans.IO
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class

e :: IOT [] ()
e = do
  x <- lift [1,2]
  sequenceIO [print (x :: Int)]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  _ <- runIOT e -- prints nothing

  [a,b] <- runIOT e  -- a, b :: ()  -- prints nothing
  b `seq` pure ()  -- prints 2  (even though  () `seq` pure ()   should be equal to  pure ())
  a `seq` pure ()  -- prints 1
```

The notion of "a monad transformer for a particular monad" is not well-defined. One may be "a monad transformer `t` such that `t Identity` is isomorphic to `IO`", and the generic construction you point out does satisfy that definition. The myth that there is no "IO monad transformer" comes from a mix of (1) if you make strong enough requirements for what that even means it may indeed not exist, (2) when it does exist, there may be no use case for such a thing.

Another generic construction that may be relevant is the [free monad transformer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Free.html). `FreeT IO` is a monad transformer and it has IO in it.

Comment: A "monad transformer for a particular base monad `b`" is in my view well defined: as you say, it is a transformer `t` such that `t Identity` is isomorphic to `b`. It is useful to talk about a "transformer for a given monad" because that's what a programmer usually needs in the code (to combine two or more monads).  Also, since `FreeT IO Identity` is isomorphic to `Free IO` but not isomorphic to `IO`, I would not say that `FreeT IO` is a monad transformer for `IO`.

Comment: The usual definition of monad transformer is that there must be a monad morphism `m a -> t m a`. This is not enough to make it useful. For example, `t m a = Unit` is useless but satisfies the requirement of having a monad morphism. There must be more laws for monad transformers to be useful. For example, there must be a non-degeneracy law of some kind.

Comment: You can quotient `FreeT IO` by a suitable equivalence relation.

Comment: You say in your answer that "t Identity is isomorphic to IO" for the construction in my question. I thought so too, but now I looked back and see that `IOT Identity` is actually not `IO` but instead `IOT Identity a = IO Unit -> IO a`. And in general `BaseT base Identity a = base Unit -> base a` and not just `base a`. So, `BaseT` is a transformer for the (valid) monad `base Unit -> base a`.

Comment: The isomorphism assumes that `forall a. m a -> IO a` denotes monad morphisms.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I forgot about that requirement. The type of monad morphisms `forall a. a -> IO a` is isomorphic to `Unit` because there is only one monad morphism `Identity -> m` for any monad `m`.